# Java, Simulating Browser

Tags: java, html, httpurlconnection

I am writing a small java program/api to programatically login/ (do a hthp post with login credentials) to this http://web2sms.ke.airtel.com

For me to post, I need parameter(key and value for the login form). When I render the form via browser, the key/name keep changing everytime  to  but when I fetch the page via java code below the key is always contact f_1.number, therefore meaning the server in  my thinking the server is differentiating if a page is fetched from from a browser or not. How can I simulate a browser and get the figures to be rendered by browser?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 *
 * @author Dell
 */
public class AirtelWeb2Sms {

    String link = "http://web2sms.ke.airtel.com";
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private boolean on = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AirtelWeb2Sms();
    }

    public AirtelWeb2Sms() {
        login();
    }

  private void login(){
      Map <String, String> parameters = new HashMap();
      try{
           URL url = new URL(link);
           URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if(inputLine.contains("<div id=\"loginform\">"))
                {
                    on=true; 
                }

                if(on && (inputLine.contains("input")||inputLine.contains("select"))&& inputLine.contains("name")&& inputLine.contains("value")){
                 //   System.out.println(inputLine);
                  String[] tokens = inputLine.split("\" ");
                    String key="", value="";
                    for(String str: tokens){
                        if(str.contains("name=")){
                            key=str.substring(str.indexOf("\"")+1);
                         }
                        if(str.startsWith("value")){
                            value=str.substring(str.indexOf("\"")+1);
                         }
                        if(key.contains(".number")){
                            value="+25473DummyNumber";
                        }
                        if(key.contains(".passwd")){
                            value="dymmerPassword";
                        }
                        if(key.contains(".language")){
                            value="en";
                        }
                     }
                    parameters.put(key, value=value.replace("&quot;", "\""));
                    System.out.println(key+":"+value);
                }
                if(inputLine.contains("<input type=\"submit\""))
                {
                    on=false; 
                }
            }
            doSubmit(link+"index.hei", parameters);
           }
            catch(Exception ex){
               System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
  } 
  public void doSubmit(String url, Map<String, String> data) throws Exception 
  { 
      URL siteUrl = new URL(url); 
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) siteUrl.openConnection(); 
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); conn.setDoOutput(true); 
      conn.setDoInput(true); DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream()); 
      Set keys = data.keySet(); 
      Iterator keyIter = keys.iterator(); String content = "";
      for(int i=0; keyIter.hasNext(); i++) {
          Object key = keyIter.next(); 
          if(i!=0) { 
              content += "&"; 
          } 
          content += key + "=" +data.get(key);
      } 
      System.out.println(content); 
      out.writeBytes(content); 
      out.flush(); 
      out.close(); 
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); 
      String line = ""; 
      while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
          System.out.println(line); } in.close(); 
  }


}
```

Comment: Surely this will depend on the server - please give more detail.  Also, what does "the server in my thinking the server is differencing" mean?

Comment: Hi, I meant differentiating i.e the server can tell its not from a browser

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the ["User-Agent"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) HTTP header to some value that a real browser would send. You can check what's your browser's user-agent string by visiting http://whatsmyuseragent.com/.

Comment: Hi, I tried setting the useragent by still cannot get the varying name/key that the browser always renders. If you can just for example what is the key/name for the username and password field. Evertime you render the page it will be a new one where else everytime i render the page from the program, its always have a 1. ie f_1.number and f_1.passw

Comment: Perhaps it's not the user-agent header that causes the difference. It's impossible to say for sure without knowing more about the server side. Use some tool like the Web Console in Firefox to see all the details of the request that your browser sends, and try to reproduce the exact same request from your program.